# How to wrap selectdatewidget select in divs with crispy forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

Im using crispy forms and bootstrap3, and I want to display the selectdatewidget selects in the same line like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_startdate_day" class="control-label col-lg-2">
       Startdate
    </label>

    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <select class="form-control" id="id_startdate_day" name="startdate_day">
                <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <select class="form-control" id="id_startdate_month" name="startdate_month">
                <option value="1">jan</option><option value="2">feb</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <select class="form-control" id="id_startdate_year" name="startdate_year">
                <option value="2013" selected="selected">2013</option><option value="2014">2014</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to make my own template for the field, but I can't seem to "split" `{% crispy_field field %}`

I have tried `{% crispy_field field.1 %}` `{% crispy_field field.2 %}` `{% crispy_field field.3 %}` , but I get this error: `Failed lookup for key [1]`

Anyone know how to "split" the crispy_field field ? Or is there another solution?

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: Had the same problem. I'd like to see a solution for this, but until then I just set the widget to `DateInput(attrs = { 'type': 'date' })`. This gives me an HTML5 date input type with format support; better than a TextInput but worse than a SelectDateWidget.